# Get service version by port with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I wonder how can I get the service version by port

I know how to scan the port and find the service but how to get the version

Here is example of result with nmap

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE  VERSION
80/tcp  open  http     Google httpd 2.0 (GFE)
```

Here is part of my code

```
for port in range(1,65535):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)

    # returns an error indicator
    result = s.connect_ex((target,port))
    if result ==0:
        #print ("Port: %s => service name: %s" %(port, socket.getservbyport(port, protocolname))) 
        service = socket.getservbyport(port, protocolname)
        if(service):
            print("Port {} is open {} ".format(port,service))
        else:
            print("Port {} is open ".format(port))  
            
    s.close()
```

The result is:

```
Port 80 is open http 


Port 443 is open https
```

Comment: Hey mate, welcome to stackoverflow! the `socket.getservbyport` function simply checks some kind of local DB that correlates port numbers with services. kind of like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). it doesn't send any packets to any server, and certainly isn't capable of preforming service discovery.

Comment: Service discovery is quite complex as it has to account for many potential services for each port. it might "guess" which tests are more likely "succeed" in detecting the service listening on a given port, but for a truly complete solution you're gonna have to test them all. HTTP, that's easy. if you're going for many services... good luck. Or, perhaps some kind of [nmap-python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/python3-nmap/) is in order. you could also extract nmap's logic as it's [open-source](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/2fcfac93292f65a7ca67294d48061fc45e1b323f/service_scan.cc)

Comment: Just to further drive the point - if there is an HTTP server listening on port 25, your script will "detect" it as SMPT.

Comment: @Yarin_007 thank you , yes  nmap-python wrapper will be good